# c++ how to fill empty width with more than one character?

Tags: c++

Consider following code :

```
cout.width(5);
cout.fill('x');
cout << 10 << endl;
```

The result should be : `xxx10`

Is there a way to make the result looks like : `xyz10` ??

I do aware that this can be achieved by looping, but I want to know whether there is a method in c++ that can help me.

Comment: There are several ways... the best one would depend on what it is you need to it for

Comment: You can always make your own manipulator which does what you want. But in the standard library there are no such functionality.

Comment: @StoryTeller just to print that way

Comment: Well than you can do it with a custom manipulator like Joachim said.

Comment: @StoryTeller how to do custom manipulator?

Comment: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/c++_practical_programming/c++_practical_programming_093.html

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
string bank_of_characters = "xyzabcdefg...";
for(int i = 0; i < customLength; ++i)
    cout << bank_of_characters[i];
cout << 10 << endl;
```

Comment: How do you compute `customLength` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 just use cout.width()-2
with 2 is number of digits you want to print